# Mimic user permissions on AWS EC2 instances using IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm setting up an AWS account with several users. Each of these users has policies attached that restrict their access to specific S3 buckets/objects and the EC2 instance types / Autoscaling Groups they can launch.

Users can launch multiple on-demand / spot instances at any given time. I want to make sure that the instances that a specific user launches have the same permissions or restrictions as the user that launched them. I'm sure I can find a way of setting up the corresponding user credentials on startup but I'd rather use roles for this.

I've been able to create a role and an instance profile to launch an EC2 instance and get S3 access with temporary credentials instead of setting up the user's access key ID and secret access key on that instance. However, is there any way of having the role mimic the user's permission so any instance launched by that user has their same restrictions? Right now a user could simply use this role to launch an EC2 instance and use that instance to access S3 buckets and objects he should not be able to access otherwise. Furthermore, some of the policies use the `aws:username` variable, which is not [available when the principal is an assumed role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html).

One workaround seems to create user-specific roles with the same policies as the ones attached to the user, but this seems like a bad approach, specially if I have a big number of users that I constantly update permissions for. I'm also unsure if I'm able to restrict users from assuming roles different than their corresponding ones. Lastly, this still would not work for policies that use the `aws:username`.

What are my options here? What would be a good practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is an IAM **permissions boundary**.

The idea is that you designate an IAM policy that describes the **maximum** that a user is allowed to do.
You can attach this policy as a permissions boundary to a principal, and it will limit how many privileges they can get.

If your users need to be able to create an IAM role (e.g., to be used in an EC2 instance profile), you can give them permission to do that under the condition that they attach a permissions boundary to that role. Here's an example of that:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CreateOrChangeRoleOnlyWithBoundary",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/XCompanyBoundaries"
                }
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

The policy is taken from a [blog post about this subject](https://www.tecracer.com/blog/2022/03/using-permission-boundaries-to-balance-security-and-developer-productivity.html) that I wrote a while ago. (Usual disclaimer: I wrote this post, it's relevant to the question)

Comment: Thanks, this seem like a step in the right direction. I'd probably create the roles myself but I was not aware I could attach an existing permission boundary. One question, though: what happens if the policies I attach to the role use the `aws:username` variable? It seems this wouldn't be resolved if the Principal is an Assumed Role and then some permissions would not apply inside the EC2 instances.

Comment: The username wouldn't be resolved, that's correct. I generally try to stay away from `aws:username` conditions unless it's a policy that grants a user permissions to generate keys for their user or change their password. Maybe it's time to invest a bit in automation and, script your resources + policies and then offer them to your users in the AWS Service Catalog.